# Python making list from values and printing certain results

Tags: python, list

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(1,76):
    input('Enter name for guest'+str( i)+': ')
    ages=int(input('Enter age for guest '+str(i)+':'))

    for x in range(20,30) in list(ages):
        print('Number of people in 20s is ' +str(x) )
```

How do I put the results in a list and print out amount of people aged in their 20s? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show is what you've tried?

Comment: I've tried what's there, I've been trying things all day I can't remember exactly, I''ll try to roughly recall.... I used a while statement like this

    while ages>=20 and ages<=29:
            print(ages)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
ages = []
for i in range(1,76):
    input('Enter name for guest'+str( i)+': ')
    ages.append(int(input('Enter age for guest '+str(i)+':')))

n = len([a for a in ages if 20 <= a < 30])
print('Number of people in 20s is ' + str(n) )
```

Comment: I thought there might be a simpler way to do it as we haven't come across len yet or append... but thanks.